# Why is a formfield's errors a list in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible that field will have more that one error?

As I know error created by clean method by

```
raise forms.ValidationError
```

more that one raise is not possible...

so, why **form.field_name.errors** it's not that **form.field_name.error**

for **form.errors** everything is logical for field not %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for a field to have more than one error. For example, you can use the [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method to add multiple errors to the same field:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        self.add_error('field1', 'error1')
        self.add_error('field1', 'error2')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple errors per field, you can instantiate `ValidationError` and add it to a particular field in the form's `clean()` method via `Form.add_error()` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error).